# Mockito mock method based on another mock method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Let's say that I have a some service class

```
class Service<T> {
  T get(int id);
  void save();
}
```

In my unit tests I mock both methods of this service using mockito. But there is a case when method save should be mocked based on mocked get method. For example if method get is called with an argument which is equal to 2 then method save should throw some exception.

I went through Mockito documentation but seems like have not found any solutions yet.

Any ideas how I can achieve this use case with Mockito?

Comment: Are you saying that you are actually testing the `Service` class?  If so, why are you mocking it?

Comment: No, for example I test controller class which uses this service class and I need to mock this service class. The thing is that method save should be mocked conditionally according to argument which is passed to get method.

Comment: So if you have different test cases which require different behaviour from the `save` method, you should stub that method differently for each test case.  If one of your test cases is expected to call `save` multiple times, you can chain the various stubbing calls together for that test case.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion needing a mocking like that should be avoided, but if you insist you can leverage the `doAnswer()` method for detailed mock handling.

Basically, you use two `Answer` instances. One that sets a flag when the method is called with 2, the other one resetting the flag.
Another answer reacts to that flag and throws an exception if needed.

```
private boolean throwExceptionNext;

@Test
public void test() {
    Service mock = Mockito.mock(Service.class);

    Mockito.doAnswer((__) -> {
        throwExceptionNext = false;
        return new Object();
    }).when(mock).get(Mockito.anyInt());
    Mockito.doAnswer((__) -> {
        throwExceptionNext = true;
        return new Object();
    }).when(mock).get(2);

    Mockito.doAnswer((__) -> {
        if (throwExceptionNext)
            throw new RuntimeException();
        return null;
    }).when(mock).save();

    mock.get(3);
    mock.save();
    mock.get(2);
    try {
        mock.save();
        Assert.fail();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    }
    mock.get(3);
    mock.save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) what you are trying to do is calling a test case from from a test case.

2) Mocking is used mainly for testing the endpoint, may be for controllers.So if your save functions needs to called again or you have to reuse the code for other test case, you should do that, it has no problem.

But what you are saying is totally against the programming paradigms for mock test cases.